# Conditional loading of ViewControllers: Temporary display of wrong ViewController

Tags: ios, swift2, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to write a login process for my app. I have embedded a navigation controller to HomeViewController and set it as the initial ViewController. **How can I fix it such that when a user enters the wrong credentials the HomeViewController will not be shown at all?**

**This is what it is doing:**

*Correct credentials entered*

Display LoginViewController -> User inputs credentials -> Display HomeViewController

*Wrong credentials entered*

Display LoginViewController -> User inputs credentials -> Display HomeViewController -> Display LoginViewController

[image: Relationship between ViewControllers]

**Code for LoginViewController** (look at the last block of code)

```
func handlingAuthentication(notification: NSNotification) {

    let dict = notification.object as! NSDictionary

        if dict["error"]! as! Bool == true {

            let errorMessage = dict["message"] as! String

            //initialize Alert Controller
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Authentication error", message: errorMessage, preferredStyle: .Alert)

            //Initialize Actions
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default){
                    (action) -> Void in
                    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            }

            //Add Actions
            alertController.addAction(okAction)

            //Present Alert Controller
            self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

         }

         else

         {
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")

                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

                self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil)

         }

}
```

**Code for HomeViewController**

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    let isUserLoggedIn = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("isUserLoggedIn")
    if(!isUserLoggedIn){
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toLoginVC", sender: self)
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
I've tried placing the code block in ViewDidLoad but I am still getting the same issue (in fact now I'm stuck on the homePage)

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let isUserLoggedIn = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("isUserLoggedIn")
    if(!isUserLoggedIn){
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toLoginVC", sender: self)
    }
    usernameLabel.text = Data.sharedInstance.userName
    getTaskDetails()
    displayTask.dataSource = self
}
```

Comment: why ur doing that in viewDidAppear?

Comment: So that I can display the homepage only if the user has successfully logged in. I'm open to suggestions on a better way to do it though

Comment: then do  that in viewDidLoad...it will be good.

Comment: It's still displaying the home page.. In fact now the login page won't even come back when an incorrect input is entered

Comment: is login page is displaying at the opening of application?

Comment: Yeah LoginViewController loads at the opening of the application

Comment: you are use a navigation or not ?

Comment: Yeah I've embedded an navigation controller to my home page (see updated post)

Comment: @noobdev put a breakpoint inside you notification and viewDidLoad and check whether the value isUserLoggedIn is expected values or not..?

Comment: Yup i'm able to get my expected value

Comment: Why doesn't the app delegate decide which to display? And why are you currently calling dismiss in the success and error cases?

Comment: @Wain what do you mean by app delegate deciding which to display? I dismiss the LoginViewController in the successful condition so that the HomeViewController will be shown

Answer (score 0):

If the main view controlled decides and displays the login you will inevitable see it on screen because it's already in the process of displaying - so it shouldn't do it. You should have some other controller, perhaps a splash view controller, which decides to show either the login or the main view.

In your login view controller the alert OK button calls dismiss, this is the reason the login controller disappears and re-appears again (after showing the main controller for a short time).